# c++11 passed std::bind in function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

it's is possible to pass in parameter an std::bind ?

I try that :

main code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <random>

#include <typeinfo> 
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

// config random generator
std::default_random_engine generator;
const char *sequence = "rgbn";
const int sizeChar = strlen( sequence)-1;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution (0, sizeChar);
auto dice = std::bind ( distribution, generator);
std::cout << "type of dice : " << typeid(dice).name() << std::endl;

// i try that
std::bind< std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(  std::default_random_engine)  > dice2 = std::bind ( distribution, generator);
// or that 
std::bind< std::uniform_int_distribution<int>,  std::default_random_engine  > dice3 = std::bind ( distribution, generator);

Map bibi;
//in a loop
randomInitializationGenerator(bibi, sequence, dice);
```

The type of auto is :

> St5_BindIFSt24uniform_int_distributionIiESt26linear_congruential_engineIjLj16807ELj0ELj2147483647EEEE

function code :

```
void  randomInitializationGenerator( Map& aremplir, const char* sequence, 
//std::bind< std::uniform_int_distribution<int>( std::default_random_engine) > dice)
std::function< std::uniform_int_distribution<int>( std::default_random_engine) > dice )
//std::function< std::uniform_int_distribution<int>, std::default_random_engine > dice )
{
  const int* sizer          = aremplir.size();
  const unsigned int finRow = sizer[1];
  const unsigned int finCol = sizer[0];
  for(unsigned int y = 0; y < finCol; ++y)
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < finRow; ++x)
      aremplir.set(y, x, sequence[ dice()]);
}
```

In `randomInitializationGenerator` param have no the good type, so no possible to do `dice()` if i try with `auto dice = std::bind ( distribution, generator)`.

Others ways
`std::bind< std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(  std::default_random_engine)  > dice2 = std::bind ( distribution, generator);` generate a compilation error `no the right type`

```cpp
error required from 'typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type std::bind(_Func&&, _BoundArgs&& ...) [with _Func = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807u, 0u, 2147483647u>); _BoundArgs = {}; typename std::_Bind_helper<std::__or_<std::is_integral<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type>, std::is_enum<typename std::decay<_Tp>::type> >::value, _Func, _BoundArgs ...>::type = std::_Bind<std::uniform_int_distribution<int> (*())(std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 16807u, 0u, 2147483647u>)>]'
```

Best regards.

Comment: This all looks a lot like aimless guessing. Which book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "a bind"; it is a function, not an object.

If you really need to store the result, store a `std::function`:

```
std::function<int()> dice3 = std::bind(distribution, generator);
```

Note that `dice3` has no parameters, because `generator` was already bound to `distribution` and there's nothing left to do (which is, after all, the whole point!).